# Tapestry quickstart build failing while adding the archetype using maven in intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, tapestry

Adding the following archetype:
GroupId : org.apache.tapestry, 
ArtifactId : quickstart, 
version : RELEASE

> CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar"
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.3.2
>   -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.vamshi -DartifactId=tapestry.two -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.tapestry -DarchetypeArtifactId=quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:RELEASE:generate
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli)
>
> > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>> [INFO]  [INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources
> >     @ standalone-pom <<< [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> >     maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
> >     --- [INFO] Generating project in Batch mode [INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from
> >     [org.apache.tapestry:quickstart:5.4.1] found in catalog remote 
> >     ....
> >     ....
>
> The build is failing with this error: [ERROR]
>   ResourceManager.getResource() parse exception [ERROR]
>   org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error,
>   Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : "" at
>   archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/mybootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot[line
>   16, column 21]
>       at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:151)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:437)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1533)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:343)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processTemplate(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:770)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFileSet(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:571)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processTemplates(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:820)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processArchetypeTemplates(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:545)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFilesetProject(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:663)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.processFilesetModule(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:596)
>       at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:207)

Comment: Does it fail only in IDEA or in command line Maven as well?

Comment: You could solve this problem using an older maven-archetype-plugin.
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://tapestry.apache.org should work.

Comment: It does fail in command line Maven

Comment: The command will lead to a 
```
[INFO] No catalog defined. Using internal catalog
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
1: internal -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-archetype (An archetype which contains a sample archetype.)
``` 

Error in my case. Did it work for you?